# Plotting a list in real time

Tags: plotting

I would like to use Mathematica for a presentation and have a list plotted in front of my audience, one coordinate at a time.

How would I go about plotting a list progressively in real-time, ie the coordinates {1,y1} first, then one second after the coordinates {2,y2}, etc... ?

Something with Manipulate so that I could switch on and off this option would be nice, but I don't see any function in the documentation that would let me plot lists in real time.

Comment: I think you're confusing a few terms here... plotting in "real time" does not mean what your question describes. What you probably want is to display a pre-computed list of points sequentially, with a reasonable time delay, correct? If so, try using `Manipulate` (or `Animate`) by indexing the list in steps of 1.

Comment: `list=RanomdInteger[10,10]; Animate[ListPlot[Take[list, i], 
  PlotRange -> {{1, Length[list]}, {Min[list], Max[list]}}], {i, 1, 
  Length[list], 1}]`

Comment: @rm-rf you're correct, I want to display a pre-computed list of points sequentially

Comment: @Szabolcs why is it that when I evaluate your commands the whole list is being plotted for a second and then after this delay only it starts plotting from x = 1?

Comment: @Stefan Well, that's why it was a comment and not an answer (despite the recent meta thread).  I assumed the OP would sort out the details.

Comment: @su1 I don't see that behaviour with v9.

Comment: @Szabolcs ahh. it was a comment! ;) i knew it may sound quite picky. was just curious, if i did miss something. but now that i know it is a comment...changes the whole picture indeed.

Comment: @Stefan Sometimes I might not have the time or be willing to put in the effort to write a good answer.  If I post an answer, people will surely start commenting about how it could/should have been improved ...  Maybe here I shouldn't have commented, as it was clear that someone would answer within half an hour the most.

Comment: @Szabolcs nevermind...although i've to say, that your comment would've been quite an option to post an answer anyways.

Comment: @Stefan Point taken, it might not have been the best course of action, as I do mostly agree with [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/posting-answers-in-comments).  I was completely aware that the plot range I chose was not ideal but I wasn't willing to spend time to make it pretty at that time, and I was hoping that the example will be enough to help the OP.  The vertical plot range should be expected too.  (Actually I wasn't even sure if the question was going to stay open.)

Comment: @Szabolcs ;) I know exactly what you're talking about...many times (and you even much longer) i've had the same impression and was just thinking: "all the effort and in the end, they are closing it ... (e.g. starting processes in background etc.). But what I think is quite educational, is that you're not saying "Take the Index", but take the range from a to i. And this does the trick, since anything else is just a point varying its y position at x=0. You know what I mean? Maybe you can nice it up with extracting points from a plot and feed this into...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do display the list point by point, you can simply use the animation controls of the Manipulate and hit the little plus button beside the control.  Then to increment you click the plus and to decrement you hit the minus.  You can also "play" the animation, and pause it when you want it.  There are also controls to slow down (or speed up) the animation.

[image: Manipulate with animation controls open]

Alternatively, if you want a button like control, the following code could do what you want.

```
    list = With[{k = .1}, Table[{t, Exp[-k t]}, {t, 0, 30}]];
    Manipulate[
     ListPlot[list[[1 ;; currentPoint]], PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}, 
      PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}], {{currentPoint, 1}, 0, 30, 1, 
      Row[{Button["Next Point", 
          If[currentPoint < 31, currentPoint++, currentPoint = 31]], 
        Button["Previous Point", 
          If[currentPoint > 1, currentPoint--, currentPoint = 1]]}] &}]
```